# jQuery hover() function coloring all 'a' tags inside div instead of just the one hovered over

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a navigation menu with "a" tags for menu items. I want to specify the hover color (black) when I hover over an 'a' tag with jQuery. The problem is that jQuery is making all 'a' tags become black when I hover over, not just the one tag I am hovering.

```js
/*specifies hover color of items in main menu*/
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("#spread-out-menu a").hover(function(){
    $("#spread-out-menu a").css("color", "black");
  }, function(){
    $("#spread-out-menu a").css("color", "#C10000");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spread-out-menu">
  <h3><a href="#">Industries</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">Services</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">About Us</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">Insights</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">Careers</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">Contact Us</a></h3>
</div>
```

Note that I have some css already applied (color of links) and that I am overriding it with jQuery. What should I do to make the hover effect apply to one element at a time?

Comment: Change `$("#spread-out-menu a").css...` to `$(this).css...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to take effect only on the hovered element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#spread-out-menu a").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "black");
  }, function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#C10000");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spread-out-menu">
  <h3><a href="#">Industries</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">Services</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">About Us</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">Insights</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">Careers</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#">Contact Us</a></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I thought that "this" works the same as the element first selected, I see that there is some difference now.

Comment: I will but they have this weird rule where I have to wait 12 min before I can accept an answer. One min left!